# Does license matter if I host a maven repository?

Tags: licensing, legal, maven

- If I make a maven repository available for others to use, do I have
  to get permission form the authors of those software that I host in
  my repository even if they are free software?
- Can I host free software libraries under any license or should they
  have compatible licenses?

Comment: Why would you be hosting the software rather than proxy'ng from Maven central?  Or are you looking to host something that isn't in Maven Central?

Answer (score 1):

Free software can be **redistributed without restrictions** (other than providing the source code, which is required in some licenses, but I assume that is actually what you would be redistributing).

The license of the libraries you host does not need to be the same or compatible, *for redistribution purposes*. If you do not change the source code in any of those libraries (e.g. mixing them up), you should be fine.